# pyqgis processing, grass: --overwrite does not work

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I have a QGIS plugin that tries to call the `v.clean` algorithm multiple times in a row and use the same output file each time the algorithm runs through. But even though I set the `--overwrite` parameter to true (as found in the [grass manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.clean.html)), the output can't be overwritten and instead I get the error

```
 ERROR 1: A file system object called 'C:\Users\...\Desktop\output.gpkg' already exists.
```

in the QGIS log. I can still run the plugin, but only the `snap` algorithm of the following code will be applied to my line layer:

```
    output = self.dlg.directory.text()

    params_snap = {
        'input' : input_2,
        'type' : 1,
        'tool' : 1,
        'threshold' : 0.000095,
        'output': output,
        'error' : 'memory:',
        'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 2
    }
    processing.run('grass7:v.clean', params_snap)

    params_break = {
        'input': input_2,
        'type': 1,
        'tool': 0,
        'threshold': 0.1,
        '-c': True,
        'output': output,
        'error': 'memory:',
        '--overwrite': True,
        'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 2
    }
    processing.runAndLoadResults('grass7:v.clean', params_break)
```

The path and name of the ouput are from a QFileDialog. If the information is needed: The input file is a temporary file.

If I set a different output file for each part of the processing the code runs fine and without errors, but since I will use more than only two algorithms creating and deleting files over and over again will just slow the plugin down.

I use the current QGIS LTR 3.4.

Comment: the grass manual can diverge from the way QGis uses the tool. I cannot test right now, but i suspect that QGis uses another keyword for `--overwrite`. I suggest running this tool once using the QGis interface and then looking at the processing history to find out exactly how QGis runs this tool

Comment: The GUI version of the GRASS 7 tool in QGIS 2.18 doesn't have an option to specify overwriting. Does it in QGIS 3.4?

Comment: @PauloRaposo it does not, but you can choose consecutive processes with the same output file. In the log grass uses `--ouverwrite` and `-o` at the same time, but neither of them, nor both of them work.

Answer (score 4):

> but since I will use more than only two algorithms creating and
>   deleting files over and over again will just slow the plugin down.

Anyway files are created and deleted whether you want it or not (see your ERROR 1 message), so if `--overwrite` parameter do not work - as workaround you can manually check if file exist and delete it before starting `grass7:v.clean`.

Here is the code:

```
import os
if os.path.exists(output): 
    os.remove(output)
```

Another workaround is to use `subprocess` module to call cmd variant of the command. Here is example:

```
import subprocess
clipper = r'D:\source\nts_index_250k.shp'
tiles = '117D 117A 116O 116P'.split()
for tile in tiles:
    warp = '''gdalwarp -cutline {clipper} -cwhere "'TILE_NAME' = '{tile}'" {infile} {outfile}'''.format(clipper=clipper,
        tile=tile,
        infile=infile,
        outfile=tile + infile
        )
    subprocess.call(warp)
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you execute this code: `print(processing.algorithmHelp('grass7:v.clean'))` with QGIS Python console, you may notice that `--overwrite` is absent in parameters description.

But if you run the same tool using QGIS interface and check for `Log` tab you may notice that `--overwrite` parameter is used somehow. That is because you may run every grass tool using cmd/shell (avoiding pyQgis API).

Here is v.clean log results: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOUJa.png)

**EDIT 2:**

Also you may try to insert string `--overwrite` in these paramaters:

```
GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO: v.out.ogr output data source options (dsco)

    Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterString

    Accepted data types:
        - str
        - QgsProperty

GRASS_VECTOR_LCO: v.out.ogr output layer options (lco)

    Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterString

    Accepted data types:
        - str
        - QgsProperty
```

Comment: I do not really know how the second solution works. Could you explain the benefits of it compared to the first solution? If I try the first solution I get a `WinError 32`, the process cannot access the file because it is used by another process. I do not use `RunAndLoadResults`, so QGIS does not load the output of the first time v.clean runs through. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @gHupf See update